# In what order should I play the difficulties in The Last Of Us?

Tags: achievements, the-last-of-us

I have just played through The Last Of Us on **hard** and now I'm aiming for the platinum trophy. In order to get that I need to get the trophies awarded for completing the game on **easy** - **survivor** and **easy+** - **survivor+**.

My question is in what order I should play the different difficulty modes. **Easy** - **hard** are already completed so I've **survivor** and **easy+** - **survivor+** left.

It really depends on these questions:

Is **survivor+** unlocked when **hard+** is completed or do I have to play **survivor** first?
If yes, is the trophy for completing **survivor** awarded when completing **survivor+**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must play survival first and yes the trophy is awarded after you complete survival+.

Comment: So since I have completed hard I should go **survival** and then **survival+**?

Comment: yes it would be the best way to go about it.

Comment: It's not the best. It's the only way to get to survival+ (I think).

Comment: I am not positive if this will give you your survival win but for one less playthrough you could start a survival, and beat one chapter. Then go to chapter select and continue the game but on survival+.

Comment: @AdamP You can achieve all the completion trophies in two playthroughs using the glitch. See [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122188/does-using-the-difficulty-glitch-in-the-last-of-us-unlock-the-survivor-trophi) question

Answer (score -1):

I recommend - that is, if you are adventurous enough - to start on Normal, then - skip game mode plus if you want to - and then proceed in the same fashion.