# Does using the difficulty glitch in "The Last of Us" unlock the Survivor+ trophies?

Tags: achievements, the-last-of-us

It is apparently possible to switch from your first playthrough (where you unlock Survivor difficulty) directly to a Survivor+ playthrough via a glitch with Chapter Select. Does completing a "Survivor+" run in this way count for trophy completion?

The glitch is where you start a new game+, play through to "20 Years Later", and then start a new game via the chapter-select and pick Hometown on Survivor+ difficulty.

This only works if you delete the patches from your system, but they can apparently be re-downloaded once you've saved on Survivor+ mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does. I beat the game on normal my first run through. I just beat it on survivor+ using that glitch, and all difficulty trophies unlocked.

Comment: Can you confirm that this definitely unlocked the 'Survivor' trophy and not just 'survivor+'?

Comment: @Colin I can confirm that it grants both Survivor and Survivor+. Also regular and + for every difficulty lower. It might take a bit of time for the trophies to show up on the main screen. Don't freak out :-)

Comment: @Zxaos Thanks, sorry to be a pain but how does this work with items and upgrades that should carry over from your original game? will I have nothing because my Survivor game only got to chapter 1 or will I have all the stuff from my original play through on Hard?

Comment: @Colin If you use the glitch, you should get your stuff from hard. I did hard, glitch, survivor+ and had all of my gear, upgrades, etc (at least all the ones that are supposed to carry over). Note that your collectibles *will* be empty in +, but the game internally keeps track of the ones you had in previous playthroughs for trophy purposes so it's just that they don't show up in your inventory so they can be picked up again.

Comment: Thanks. I have done this myself now and I can confirm that this is correct.