# Does the difficulty glitch still work in The Last of Us Remastered?

Tags: the-last-of-us-remastered

[The difficulty glitch, as referred to in this previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122188/does-using-the-difficulty-glitch-in-the-last-of-us-unlock-the-survivor-trophi), allowed you to start a New Game + at a different difficulty than you finished the original The Last of Us game on.

Does this glitch still work on the PlayStation 4 remastered version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! Just used it, jumped straight to NG+ on grounded.